# Unbound install/config error with mounting

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mount, dns

https://www.prado.it/2012/04/14/how-to-configure-unbound-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Following this guide to install Unbound for DNS purposes and I have ran in to a problem with the following cmd:

> sudo mount --bind -n /dev/log /etc/unbound/dev/log
>
> sudo mount --bind -n /dev/random /etc/unbound/dev/random

I get the following sysntax error:

root@pc:/etc/unbound# mount(2) system call failed: Not a directory.

I have used the chown cmd, and the chmod cmd thinking it may be an issue with permissions, and it didn't help.

I have searched for awhile on the net for someone who has had this problem yet I've seen no others.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.04

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Why do you use an outdated guide for Ubuntu 11.10 to configure Ubuntu 18.04? Take a look at `man mount`, you need to specify two directories for the `mount --bind`-command. Neither `/dev/log` nor `/dev/random` are directories, `/dev/log` is a link to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log` and `/dev/random` is a character device.